# Key listener for android

Tags: android, keylistener

I am designing an application for which i need to read out the characters typed by the person in a text field aloud . Can I do such a thing with android? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TextWatcher](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html&ei=k9bzT5mEPMftrAe97IjiBg&usg=AFQjCNF5WNMSztKb7uY5NdI7TsXHDjv_QQ&sig2=s2iC_z_vHZ2kjrFH7JgVyQ) for reading characters typed by the person in a text field as:

**FIRST SOLUTION :**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){ 
@Override   
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {   
       //GET TEXT HERE AFTER TYPING DONE BY PERSON   
    }   
@Override   
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count,int after){  
      //GET TEXT HERE BEFORE TYPING START BY PERSON   
    }   
@Override   
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
   //GET TYPED CHAR HERE 
  }   
});
```

**SECOND SOLUTION:** you can also get typed char by user from edittext using [setOnKeyListener](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CHgQFjAF&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html&ei=zNbzT-7qNMryrQfa89nPBg&usg=AFQjCNGAaxjBt2TI3FJ_vmjXgMYsgHoFlg&sig2=ZGhE031pOmYWLR7pekdLpQ) as:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnClickListener(){   
public boolean onKey(View v,int keyCode,KeyEvent event)   
{   
     String str=editText.getText(); //GET TYPED CHAR HERE  
     return false;   
}   
});
```